# Mui dynamic column names

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to achieve this, creating data grid with MUI v5 and rendering some kind of select or drop-down or input field, with which the name of the column will be changed dynamically, I've tried a lot of variants but in the end something gets buggy or the component breaks completely.

Comment: You mean that you want to edit the header of some table?

Comment: Yes, creating table with some header names and then be able to change them